# Single post template not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, templates

page-webinars.php:

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Webinars
 */
?>
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('webinars')));
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part('loop-webinars'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

loop-webinars.php:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

single-webinars.php:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div>
    <?php
    the_post();
    the_content();
    ?>
</div>
```

Looks like everything's correct. Page displays necessary template, but single not working.

Comment: Please make the question clear.  "Single not" *what, excactly*? Is the single page loading? Are you sure? If you know it is (or isn't), how do you know? If it IS loading, is it not displaying the content?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use WordPress loop.
Try with this code in your `single-webinars.php` file.

```
<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
    <?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?>
    <div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php // End of the loop.
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It had just to "reactivate" theme...